# Where in with mysql or better?

Tags: mysql

Here is my actual query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"select ids_billets from pref_tags where id='$_GET[id]'");
$tags_ids = $result->fetch_object();

$result = mysqli_query($link,"select id, html from pref_posts where id in ($tags_ids->ids_billets)");
while($posts = $result->fetch_object()) {
  .....
}
```

I have ids in one varchar field of the pref_tags table (ids_billets) - example : "12,16,158"

Is there a better way to query this?
Thanks

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should be using [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add values to your query. **Never** add `$_GET` or `$_POST` data directly to the query string.

Comment: even if there is a user admin control before?

Comment: No excuses. Period. The reason people get in trouble is because they make assumptions. Code like this has a way of being repurposed, used in other contexts where that security may not be present. It's also an extremely bad habit to get into. The consequences of a single mistake of this sort are simply too severe to take chances. Do it properly, which is *not* hard, and you won't have injection bugs.

Comment: You're right... How could I make my query for this case (example)? I have difficulties to understand on php.net...

Comment: Parameterized queries using `bind_param` when executing are the most straight-forward way of doing it. There's several educational links in my first comment. Your queries end up looking like `WHERE id=?` and then you bind against that placeholder before executing. As a bonus you can prepare a statement and execute it N times with different bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of one row with a comma-separated list, I would create a new table linking posts to tags, with one row per post/tag combo, i.e.:

```
posts
---------------------
post_id | html | etc.


posts_tags
----------------
post_id | tag_id

tags
------------------------
tag_id | tag_name | etc.
```

Then do something like this:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.html
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt
ON p.post_id = pt.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t
ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE t.tag_name = ?
```

Or if you already have the `tag_id`, like you seem to:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.html
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt
ON p.post_id = pt.post_id
WHERE pt.tag_id = ?
```

You can also do the same query in a different form, using a subquery:

```
SELECT post_id, html
FROM posts
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM posts_tags WHERE tag_id = ?)
```

Also, look at [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which will make it easy to avoid the serious SQL injection problems your current code has.

Comment: The tables will be huge with this structure, no? If I have +100000 posts, The table posts_tags an tags will be enormous... What about performances? Thanks

Comment: @user2670167 If you have a lot of posts, wouldn't your `ids_billets` column be huge? This should have a huge performance advantage, because you don't need to run two queries, and you can use an index on the `post_tags` table (I would add a primary key on `posts_tags(tag_id, post_id)`, an index on `posts_tags(post_id)`, a primary key on `posts(post_id)` and a primary key on `tags(tag_id)`.

Comment: Ok, I have a problem to set the insert query (I'm looking for a one insert query solution). I have 3 tables, to fill the tags table it's ok in one query, but to fill the posts_tags I need id of previously inserted ids... How to get all that in one time without querying in loop for each tag to obtain their id?...

Comment: @user2670167 I wasn't aware that you could insert into multiple tables in one INSERT. The way I would do it is to `INSERT INTO posts ...` then use [mysqli_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), then `INSERT INTO posts_tags ...`. Doesn't your current solution require inserting into `posts`, then getting the ID, then updating `tags`?

Comment: Ok, so I have to make a query for each table for each tag.
The user can post several tags with its post...

Comment: And if I want all the posts where a tag is?.. I must do a query "where tag_name = xxx"? Is it ok to make a query on a text field when the table is huge?...

Comment: @user2670167 You can insert multiple rows into the same table in one query, just put a comma between each row: `INSERT INTO posts_tags (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 7)`. To find all posts with a particular tag, the queries in my answer work. You can also get posts in multiple tags by using `WHERE tag_id IN (...)`. Using a text field is completely fine as long as there's an index on it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently having problems on query to have all tags associated to the post... I'm lost in the inner joins :-(

Comment: Ok! Found the query! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** put multiple values in a single column, because doing so breaks [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Have a look at that link for examples of the problems you're likely to come across, and how to fix them.

Rather, create a separate table where you can have the ID and the Tag ID in separate columns. Then you can pull back the IDs in a subquery in your second example query, *and* get the benefits of being able to search for and manipulate individual IDs in other queries.

Comment: I'm sorry, the organisation of the website could not permit an other structure than put ids in a field...

Comment: You have my sympathy. In that case, you may also find the function `FIND_IN_SET` useful.